# Qual o significado da taxa de mutação em algoritmos genéticos?

Tags: otimização, inteligência-artificial

Olá.
Digamos que eu defina uma taxa de mutação de 5% em um AG. O que isso significa?

- Que itero sobre toda a população e, para cada indivíduo, itero sobre todos os genes dele e faço uma mudança com 5% de probabilidade? Aqui, toda a população vai ter cerca de 5% dos seus genes alterados.
- Que itero sobre toda a população e, para cada indivíduo, faço a mudança de um gene aleatório dele com 5% de probabilidade? Aqui, ao fim da mutação, cerca de 5% da população vai ter um gene alterado.

Outra coisa...Convencionalmente, a mutação é aplicada sobre toda a população, incluindo os pais selecionados, ou só na prole? A segunda opção é biologicamente mais plausível.

Answer (score 1):

A taxa de mutação se refere à quantidade de indivíduos da população que sofrerão mutação.

Ela é, geralmente, muito pequena e serve para manter a variabilidade genética dos cromossomos ao passar das gerações.

Você pode, naturalmente, arbitrar outro parâmetro na sua implementação que controla a porcentagem de genes que serão mutados durante o processo.

Em relação à outra pergunta, em geral, a mutação vem logo após o cruzamento. Assim, ela atua apenas na prole.

Sugiro o *Manual de Computação Evolutiva e Metaheurística* como introdução ao tema.